# how to randomly load an image when users reload the page on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, random, fetch

I am new to rails. I am trying to fetch a randomly image from an API when users reload the page.

In the html, I have,

```
<%= image_tag id: 'login_gif', width: "370" %>
```

In javascript, I have,

```
let loginGif = document.getElementById('login_gif')
fetch("https://aws.random.cat/meow")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(pic => { (loginGif.attr("src", pic.file ))})
```

How do I do this? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Try `loginGif.src = pic.file`.

Comment: What would your `pic` json look like? can you add an sample. Please post your browser console output as well if possible

Comment: it just looks like this: {file: "https://purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io/i/1oBoxmb.jpg"}
file: "https://purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io/i/1oBoxmb.jpg"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0):

You used the jQuery `.attr()` method... But `loginGif` is not a jQuery object.

Try `.then(pic => { (loginGif.src = pic.file)})`

Comment: Hello thanks for your help. I tired the solution. No image was loaded on the page.